# bash compare regex expression and not the variable

Tags: regex, bash, loops

I want to remove all file contain a substring in a string, if does not contain, I want to ignore it, so I use regex expression

```
str=9009
patt=*v[0-9]{3,}*.txt
for i in "${patt}"; do echo "$i"     
        if ! [[ "$i" =~ $str ]]; then rm "$i" ; fi    done
```

but I got an error :

```
*v[0-9]{3,}*.txt
rm: cannot remove '*v[0-9]{3,}*.txt': No such file or directory
```

file name like this : mari_v9009.txt femme_v9009.txt mari_v9010.txt femme_v9010.txt

Comment: I think you may be confusing regular expressions and glob patterns (aka filename wildcard expressions). See [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globbing-and-regex-so-similar-so-different) for some discussion of the differences. In particular, "{3,}" is regex-speak for "3 or more", but is not valid in a glob pattern.

Comment: @locklockM, The pattern problem is really deflecting from what you're asking. Do you have files that do NOT match "v with 3 or more digits" ? If yes, do you want to delete those or not? If not, why post that red herring?

Comment: Why don't you just do `rm *v9009.txt` ? Or, if you must store the number in a variable, `rm *v"$str".txt`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, removed incorrect comment.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>bash filename expansion does **not** use regular expressions. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion</strike>

To find files with "v followed by 3 or more digits followed by .txt" you'll have to use bash's extended pattern matching.
A demonstration:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ touch mari_v9009.txt femme_v9009.txt mari_v9010.txt femme_v9010.txt
$ touch foo_v12.txt
$ for f in *v[0-9][0-9]+([0-9]).txt; do echo "$f"; done
femme_v9009.txt
femme_v9010.txt
mari_v9009.txt
mari_v9010.txt
```

---

What you have with this pattern `for i in *v[0-9]{3,}*.txt` is:

1. first, bash performs [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) which results in

   ```
   for i in *v[0-9]3*.txt *v[0-9]*.txt
   ```
2. then, the first word `*v[0-9]3*.txt` results in no matches, and the default behaviour of bash is to leave the pattern as a plain string. `rm` tries to delete the file named literally "*v[0-9]3*.txt" and that gives you the "file not found error"
3. next, the second word `*v[0-9]*.txt` gets expanded, but the expansion will include files you don't want to delete.

---

I missed the `not` from the question.

try this: within `[[ ... ]]`, the `==` and `!=` operators are a pattern-matching operators, and extended globbing is enabled by default

```
keep_pattern='*v[0-9][0-9]+([0-9]).txt'
for file in *; do
    if [[ $file != $keep_pattern ]]; then
        echo rm "$file"
    fi
done
```

But `find` would be preferable here, if it's OK to descend into subdirectories:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended '!' -regex '.*v[0-9]{3,}\.txt' -print
# ...............................^^^
```

If that returns the files you expect to delete, change `-print` to `-delete`

Comment: parse: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
parse: line 4: `patt=*v[0-9][0-9]+([0-9]).txt

Comment: This requires `bash`, not `sh`

Comment: i use bash
#!/bin/bash

Comment: Did you `shopt -s extglob` in the script?

Comment: it works, but in package debian, I got make[2]: shopt: Command not found

Comment: you don't need to use it inside a loop: that find comand *replaces* the for-loop

Comment: but it would be delete all files, it is for that I add this "$i" =~ $str, it if there a special number like 9009, I don't want to delete these files

Comment: Apologies, I missed the `!`

Comment: nope, the logical is not that, in regex expression, if a number like 9009 exist, I don't want to remove it, you code remove all file number, so it is not that I want

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes in the `for` loop.  Then the filename globs will be interpreted:

```
for i in ${patt}; do echo "$i"
```

Comment: nope it does not work :(( I still get the same error

Comment: @locklockM How exactly does it not work?  What output do you get?

Comment: I got the same error, 
*v[0-9]{3,}.txt
rm: cannot remove '*v[0-9]{3,}.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: There is no `{m,n}` quantification in shell globs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Python.

I have tested your regex code, and found the `*` character unnecessary.
The following seems to work fine: `v[0-9]{3,}.txt`

Can you please elaborate some more on the issue?

Thanks,
Bren.

Comment: I have many files like : mari_v9009.txt femme_v9009.txt mari_v9010.txt femme_v9010.txt..., So I want to remove file name contain a substring="9009"

Comment: @locklockM Seems like you could just do `rm *v9009.txt`.

Comment: Use `rm -f` as stated in the man page, as this will not throw up an error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I just piped the error message to /dev/null.  This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash 
str=9009
patt=*v[0-9]{3,}*.txt
rm $(eval ls $patt 2> /dev/null | grep $str)
```

Comment: *v[0-9]{3,}.txt
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

Comment: You have the `2> /dev/null` in there?

Comment: str=9009
patt=*v[0-9]{3,}.txt
for i in ${patt}; do echo "$i"     
        if ! [[ "$i" =~ $str ]]; then rm $(eval ls $patt 2> /dev/null | grep $str) ; fi    done

Comment: Why are you putting this in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is not regex, this is globbing. Take a look what gets expanded:

```
# echo *v[0-9]{3,}*.txt
*v[0-9]3*.txt femme_v9009.txt femme_v9010.txt mari_v9009.txt mari_v9010.txt
```

`*v[0-9]3*.txt` obvously doesn't exists. can you clarify what files are you trying to achieve with `{3,}` ? Otherwise live it out and it will match the kind of filenames you have specified.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Comment: {3,} it is for the number starting from three numbers, like 112, 2222

Comment: In this context, `{3,}` is interpreted as a brace expansion and becomes just `3`.